# Problem with the function for printing values inside my file

Tags: c, structure

I have a problem with printing values inside a file, when i display all the values inside my file, they appear one next to each other and not downwards.

Here is my code:

```
void listaPacientes(int opcion)
{
FILE *fp;
struct paciente p;

fp=fopen(fname,"rb");

printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
printf("\t\t Lista de pacientes\n\n");
printf("========================================================\n\n");

printf("Nombre\tApellido\tTelefono\tCama_ID\n\n");

while(1)
{
fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,fp);

if(feof(fp))
{
break;
}
printf("%s\t",p.nombre);
printf("%s\t",p.apellido);
printf("%s\t",p.telefono);
printf("%d\t",p.cama_id);



}
printf("========================================================\n\n");

fclose(fp);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just change the final `\t` by a `\n` into `printf("%d\t",p.cama_id);`

```
void listaPacientes(int opcion)
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct paciente p;

    fp=fopen(fname,"rb");

    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Lista de pacientes\n\n");
    printf("========================================================\n\n");

    printf("Nombre\tApellido\tTelefono\tCama_ID\n\n");

    while(1)
    {
        fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,fp);

        if(feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s\t",p.nombre);
        printf("%s\t",p.apellido);
        printf("%s\t",p.telefono);
        printf("%d\n",p.cama_id); //<- here the modification



    }
    printf("========================================================\n\n");

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing a newline inside the loop.  This could be solved easily by adding `puts("\n")` (or `printf("\n")` if you really want to).

Note that you can also just combine everything into one `printf` call that ends in a newline:

```
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n", p.nombre, p.apellido, p.telefono, p.cama_id);
```